# How to create Custom Interface with standard directus interfaces?

Tags: directus

How to create a custom interface by using **standard directus interfaces** as a starter?

[an answer in discord](https://discord.com/channels/725371605378924594/741319150030553159/845333861981749280) uses **directus tarball**  in dependencies and [a custom vue.config.js](https://github.com/netlesh/file-image/blob/acc7a6b91590049de6654fa85fe25e92c43fef34/vue.config.js#L1) , but the rest of the import statements are still wrong.

**Here is my custom interface source code:**

Even If [all import statements of custom interface's vue file](https://github.com/netlesh/file-image/blob/acc7a6b91590049de6654fa85fe25e92c43fef34/src/fileimage.vue#L91) are correct , `directus-extension build` can't build interface because of other import statements.

Is there a better way to use standard directus interfaces ([file-image](https://github.com/directus/directus/tree/main/app/src/interfaces/file-image) or [input-rich-text](https://github.com/directus/directus/tree/main/app/src/interfaces/input-rich-text-html)) in custom interfaces?

Answer (score 4):

There has not been enough information to provided to help with debugging your issues with the file interface.

Documentation for building interfaces can be found in the Directus Docs. https://docs.directus.io/concepts/interfaces/#interfaces

I have created an interface for Directus that uses the image interface. Perhaps providing the link will be a useful resource to you showing you how I have personally implemented it. https://github.com/resauce-dev/directus-image-scout

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement the default file-image interface. Your directus-image-scout deserves a star. I will check your `rollup.config.js` file if I will need rollup instead of @directus/extensions-sdk to build custom interface.

Comment: Haha thanks, yeah, my rollup configuration is a more advanced way of doing the same thing the extensions SDK does 